# Rest operator with generics in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Consider the following code...

I would expect the spread operator to be valid code, but it ends up not being so. I'm hoping somebody with expertise in Typescript can advise on why this is...

```
export default function convertToGlobalFragment<
  T extends basicFragmentRecipe_T
>(
  fragmentFactory: (recipe: T) => configFragment_I,
  recipe: T & { matchingRules: globalMatchingRules_T }
): globalConfigFragment_I {

  let {
    matchingRules,
    ...restOfRecipe
  }: { matchingRules: globalMatchingRules_T, restOfRecipe: T } = recipe;

}
```

#### The error code

```
Property 'restOfRecipe' is missing in type 'basicFragmentRecipe_T & { matchingRules: globalMatchingRules_T; }' but required in type '{ matchingRules: globalMatchingRules_T; restOfRecipe: T; }'.ts(2741)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recipe` is `basicFragmentRecipe_T` plus `{ matchingRules: globalMatchingRules_T }` and it seems that `basicFragmentRecipe_T` does not have `restOfRecipe` prop at all.

You need to indicate the same target type  to assign `recipe`:

```
let {
    matchingRules,
    ...restOfRecipe
  }: { matchingRules: globalMatchingRules_T } & T = recipe;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let {
    matchingRules,
    ...restOfRecipe
  }: { matchingRules: globalMatchingRules_T, restOfRecipe: T } = recipe;
```

This part is wrong because recipe doesn't contain a property called `restOfRecipe` - it's `{ matchingRules: globalMatchingRules_T } & T` - where `T` is assignable to `basicFragmentRecipe_T`

You can pull out restOfRecipe without this code - let TS do the work:

```js
  let { matchingRules, ...restOfRecipe } = recipe;
```

Now restOfRecipe is of type:

[image]

```js
Pick<T & { matchingRules: globalMatchingRules_T; }, Exclude<keyof T, "matchingRules">>
```

Let's break that down.

The type of recipe is the combination of `T` and `{ matchingRules: globalMatchingRules_T; }`

To get from this type the properties except 'matchingRules' - we need to exclude matchingRules from `T` and `{ matchingRules: globalMatchingRules_T; }`. As the latter part will always contain matchingRules, we can skip checking the combination and just look at `Exclude<keyof T, "matchingRules"` to get the keys of T without 'matchingRules'.

Finally we then use `Pick<T, K>` to pick the keys of `T` (without `matchingRules`) from the type of `Recipe`, giving us the result above.